# Need to select first part of the string and eliminate rest after a character using REGEXP_SUBSTR

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
Security Compliance - P2 - United States-Region B
Sales Leadership - Sales Strategy - E1 - United States-Region A
Site Reliability Engineering - M6 - United Kingdom
```

for example my data in a column looks somewhat like above, i want to use **regex_substr()** to eliminate everything after P2, E1, and M6 etc which are in the format of 1single capital alphabet and 1 number and its only two characters.

final output looks something like this

```
Security Compliance
Sales Leadership - Sales Strategy 
Site Reliability Engineering
```

Comment: Which database are you using? Depending upon you can use instring on - and get the result. You can also use regular expression depending upon the database. Please mention which database are you using

Comment: Is that example showing three records, or one record with multiline string? Also, what have you tried and did not work?

Comment: @JimMacaulay, the database is mentioned in tags (snowflake)

Comment: Snowflake database, it’s a table column with several such values

Comment: But is your example **one** multiline value, or are they **three** values? And what have your tried?

Comment: It’s 3 values, 3 rows in that column

Comment: And what have you tried that didn't work. I suppose you looked at the regular expression documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would phrase this using a regex replacement:

```sql
SELECT col, REGEXP_REPLACE(col, ' - [A-Z][0-9] -.*', '') AS col_out
FROM yourTable;
```

This approach has an advantage over a substring approach in the event that any column value does *not* have the matching pattern, in which case the original value would be selected.

Comment: great thanks, REGEX_REPLACE is better choice, works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below function,

```
SELECT 
substr(column, 0, 
instr(column, REGEXP_SUBSTR(column, '(\w)(\d)')) -3)
FROM table;
```

Example

```
SELECT 
substr('Sales Leadership - Sales Strategy - E1 - United States-Region A', 0, 
instr('Sales Leadership - Sales Strategy - E1 - United States-Region A', REGEXP_SUBSTR ('Sales Leadership - Sales Strategy - E1 - United States-Region A', '(\w)(\d)')) -3);
```